# A point D in a triangle ABC such that $\angle DAB= \angle DBC= \angle DCA$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I got this question from a student of mine, who is participating in a math olympiad competition: How can we construct a point D in a triangle ABC such that $\angle DAB= \angle DBC= \angle DCA$? I've tried with the most common points such as barycenter or orthocenter, but nothing. I appreciate any hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe for any 2 of the angles they are angles in alternate segment?

Answer (score 6):

You are asking for so called Brocard's point of the triangle. One of constructions can be found on Wikipedia: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard_points

Answer (score 1):

draw a line $l$ at $A$ that is perpendicular to $AB.$  draw perpendicular bisector $m$ of the side $AC.$  let the lines cut at $B'.$  now draw a circle $\beta$ with center $B'$ and radius $B'A = B'C.$ the circle $\beta$ is tangent to the side $AB$ and goes through $C.$ in addition, if $D$ is point inside the triangle $ABC$ and on the circle $\beta,$  then $\angle BAD= \angle ACD.$

repeat the constructions at the other two sides and get circles $\alpha$ through $B, c$ and circle $\gamma$ through  $A, B.$

the point $D$ is the intersection of these three circles. in fact this point has a name that i am unable to recall.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe it's the notation, but I haven't been able even to perform the very first construction.

Comment: @math_failure, i had the one side wrong. i have fixed it and added some more explanation. see if it is clearer; let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Construct an equilateral triangle on the outside of two of the edges and find its midpoint. Use this to draw an arc through the two associated vertices of your original triangle. Repeat this for another side of the triangle ABC. The required point D is at the intersection of these two arcs.

[image]

Comment: Sir how to be sure that D is the required point.

Comment: In this triangle angles ADB, BDC, CDA are equal, not the ones OP asked for.

Comment: Thank you, I treid the construction but I guess @Wojowu is right.

Comment: @Wojowu - I thought I had read it carefully, but somehow I guess my mind just retained something else.